# How can I alter the default behavior of a link to an mp3 file?

Tags: download, mp3

I'd like to alter the default behavior of a link that points to an mp3 file. All major browsers always open and play this mp3 file in a new window, and I'd like instead that this file be offered as a download by the browser.

¿Any Idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

If you control the server hosting the mp3, try serving it as `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. and `Content-disposition: attachment`.

Comment: Thank You very Much!

I have made a little php script that works perfect with your idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have enough control to set the content header, you could provide instructions that say to "Right click and Save As...", I've seen a lot of web sites do this.